# Access UI components Inside controllers init method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to hide a button inside the controller's init method. But its not working. I have created a outlet to the image to access it from the controller. Dont know why the image is not get hidden.But I can do it inside the viewdidload method. Is it because the view still not loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the view will be loaded when viewdidload is called. so any changes to the existing UI should be called in view did load or view will appear

Answer (score 1):

The UI components you're talking about are all subviews of the UIView that is owned by the UIViewController that you're creating. But that UIView and its subviews aren't actually created at the time the init method is called, so you can't change them there.

`viewDidLoad` is the appropriate place for any code that only needs to run once after the view has been created, but before it has been displayed.

`viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` will run every time the view is about to or just did become visible again respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the whole view hierarchy will be loaded when the `loadView` message is sent to the controller. This message is also sent automatically the first time you access the controller's view. That's why your message to the button gets discarded in the `init` method, because the object is not yet 'unfrozen' from the `xib`/`storyboard`. And yes, the appropriate place to do your view customization would be inside the `viewDidLoad` delegate method.

PS. Also... if you want the button to be hidden upon initialization, why don't you just check its `hidden` property in your `xib`/`storyboard` ?